# HTTRACK doing partial download

Tags: web, httrack

We are using `HTTRACK` to download an entire website for offline viewing.

The problem is even downloading the whole site with level 4 (`-r4`) some links fail to work.

For example if you use httrack for capturing the site:

http://advaitasharada.sringeri.net/display/bhashya/Gita

It captures only a portion of it, but it leaves the links on the right side. The other links containing the other chapters of the Gita, is marked with #fragments.

http://advaitasharada.sringeri.net/display/bhashya/Gita#BG_C02 (the link only works when clicked on the browser)

1. Why doesn't `HTTRACK` download all the links? What to do?
2. Also the `search` is not working. It leads to the original domain of the site( which needs internet connection).

Comment: Answer to the first part: The website uses *server-side scripting*, that is, the server generates webpages *on the fly* when a request is made. HTTRack can only download static webpages and thus misses out the portions that are generated on the fly.

Comment: it is downloadable, rather large though 2.6 GB,  you could try wget

Comment: Thanks @KaranKaran and @Junme! This is what I suspected. It involves server-side scripting! Junme, I tried `wget`, but it was not working. Size is not a problem. I gave `-r6` and `HTTRACK` downloaded 6.6 GB! God knows how it got so much data! Could you please post the `wget`  command you used as an answer? Have you checked the righthand side links of the site are working?

Answer (score 0):

The website uses [server-side scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting), that is, the server generates webpages *on the fly* when a request is made. HTTRack can only download static webpages and thus misses out the portions that are generated on the fly.

Comment: Is there any other ways to download the website?